# call function of the class using two separate objects

Tags: python, function, class

I did the following code,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
        self.batch_size=5
        
    def next1(self,counter=count()):
        i = next(counter) * self.batch_size
        s = self.a[i:i + self.batch_size]
        
        return s
```

when I call next method by doing following

```
a=A()
a.next1()
#output [1,2,3,4,5]

b=A()
b.next1()
# output [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

my question is why?
as I am creating a new object so I am expecting same output`[1,2,3,4,5]` both the time.
can anyone tell me where did I go wrong?
I can not remove `i` function as it is connected to other part as well

Comment: Even if it's not the cause of the problem, it's best not to name a method `next` as that's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: The linked dupe should explain more, but essentially `counter=count()` is only evaluated once (when the class is interpreted), not twice (once per instantiation). This is the 'mutable default argument' gotcha in Python.

Comment: @sj95126 i change the name of method, still out put remain the same

Comment: @NathanielFord could you explain bit more?